# How to handle 'code generator has deoptimised styling' message from gulp-babel

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I've just employed `gulp-babel` to my gulp file with the following

```
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

return gulp.src(files.concat.js.myModule)
  .pipe(babel())
  .pipe(concat('myModule.js'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('path/to/js'));
```

...and I get the following `Note` about deoptimising the styling in my gulp output:

```
NOTE: The code generator has deoptimised the styling ... as it exceeds the max of "100KB"
```

Is this a problem?
Should I be handling this is some way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Turns out the `compact` option is set to `auto` by default which removes "superfluous whitespace characters and line terminators [...] on input sizes >100KB".

If this is not what you want, you can set the [`compact` option](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/) to false...

```
.pipe(babel({compact: false}))
```

Comment: Helped me setting this option to false in my .babelrc as well.