# BABEL Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "app.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB in Meteor

Tags: meteor, babeljs

My app.js file in meteor has exceeded the limit of 100KB 
How do I fix this now?
Does It affects my application?
Is that because of installing packages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "The code generator has deoptimised the styling of \[some file\] as it exceeds the max of "100KB"" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576341/what-does-the-code-generator-has-deoptimised-the-styling-of-some-file-as-it-e)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is not a real issue. Just a warning.
When babel compiles some code, it try to offer a readable output, but when files become big (>100KB), babel considers (by default) that it's not useful to keep this option enabled (because yes it's an option, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30879872/988941 for more information).

It's not a problem to keep it. If you don't care about readability, you can just use `compact: true`. Or `false` if you do. Only `"auto"` value (default value) will print this warning.

Comment: how to add this to the .bablerc file? Answer: see answer below.

Answer (score 17):

At first for more explanation read the [Babel documentation on Options](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options).

It is a common option of `Babel compiler` that commands *not include superfluous whitespace characters and line terminators.* sometimes ago its threshold was `100KB` but now is `500KB`.

And I advise to you disable this option in your development environment, with this code in `.babelrc` file.

```
{
    "env": {
      "development" : {
        "compact": false
      }
    }
}
```

For production environment `Babel` use the default config which is `auto`.