# Ember-cli is ignoring options .babelrc

Tags: ember.js, babeljs, ember-cli

I want to configure the babel options in my Ember app to either ignore the `data-stubs` folder, or set `compact` to false so I can silence the following error during builds:

```
[Babel: my-app > applyPatches][BABEL] 
 Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of dev/my-app/tests/data-stubs/foo.js
 as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
```

Accepted answers on StackOverflow say to configure the `.babelrc` file with `{"compact": false}`, but that isn't working with ember-cli builds. Reference Answer:
[BABEL Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "app.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192796/babel-note-the-code-generator-has-deoptimised-the-styling-of-app-js-as-it-exc/36880182)

I made a `.babelrc` file in the root folder of my ember app and have tried many different configurations:

```
{
  "ignore": ["**/data-stubs/*.js", "tests/data-stubs/*", "*tests/data-stubs/*"], //do not translate our stub files
  "compact": false,
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "compact": false
    }
  }
}
```

None has any effect and always results in the `The code generator has deoptimised the styling` error message. I also put a `.babelrc` file into the `data-stubs` folder with the same settings as above, and that isn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. Ember uses [`ember-cli-babel`](https://github.com/babel/ember-cli-babel) which states in documentation:

> If you need to customize the way that babel-preset-env configures the plugins that transform your code, you can do it by passing in any of the babel/babel-preset-env options.
>   *Note: .babelrc files are ignored by default.*

While you can configure babel and ember-cli-babel in your `ember-cli-build.js`, I think `compact` will not work because of [this open issue](https://github.com/babel/ember-cli-babel/issues/302).

However you *can* specify `exclude`.

Comment: Actually I tried that exclude and it seems to be for types of javascript/functions and not for specific files. eg. ```// don't transpile generator functions
exclude: [
      'transform-regenerator',
    ],```

but cudos to pointing out the `Note: .babelrc files are ignored by default.` that definetly helps.

Comment: yeah, the situation is actually even more complex, because every addon can bring another version of babel that should be used for the addon.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, only the [top level options](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/26c0a32c7c09700ccc8e19152c460573da65b657/packages/babel-preset-env/src/options.js#L3) destined for `@babel/preset-env` will work with `ember-cli-babel` . Unfortunately `compact` is not one of those.