# BABEL Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of undefined as it exceeds the max of 500KB

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5, babel-loader

I am receiving this warning during my local build

```
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of undefined as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
```

The `styling of undefined` doesn't seem to really describe this problem. Could anyone can help me to allocate this problem?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35192796/babel-note-the-code-generator-has-deoptimised-the-styling-of-app-js-as-it-exc